# How to access iPhone Simulator's images

Tags: ios-simulator, filesystems

Is there any way to access the internal images that the iPhone simulator uses?

For example, if I want to get the original image used for one of the default app icons (e.g. Contacts). This way I could get the highest possible resolution, and examine it for purposes of creating similar icons for my app.

Another example of an image I might want to access is the default icon for a contact:

[image]

I'm not asking for a programmatic solution (although that would work), I'm asking for a manual solution, possibly navigating the Simulator's file system using Finder.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the apps at e.g. `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/Applications`. The icon of Contacts is at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/Applications/Contacts.app/icon.png` or `icon@2x.png`. But you can't easily read them, as they are in a strange format (it's not standard PNG), you need to convert them. See for example [this article](http://www.hackthatphone.com/2x/convert_png_files.html) or [this article](http://modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/Iphone_PNG_images).

Comment: This seems very close to what I want, but it seems that that folder only gives me access to the App's icon. This was only an example of something I would want to access. What if I wanted other images the app uses, such as the default image for a contact (see the updated question)? Or, what if I wanted images the OS itself uses, such as the switch control?

Comment: Just browse through the *.app directories and look for the images you want... also the *.framework directories in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` are of interest. But it help a lot if you tell us **why** you want to access these files anyway. For normal iPhone development there are way better methods if all you need are some specific icons.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: added two more links for iphone icon images.**

You dont need to do this.

Just grab a User Interface Kit:

Heres a website you can go to to download the .psd files which you can use for your self for free:

> http://webdesignledger.com/freebi

For another library of iphone icons. This one includes the contacts icon:

> http://www.iphonestudio.co.uk/page/iphone_icon_gallery

And here are the iphone icons on the main screen made downloadable for your own use.
here are official icons in different sizes.
check the quality of the Photos icon.
wow.

> http://www.iconarchive.com/category/application/iphone-icons-by-judge.html

Hope this helps.

Let me know if it did

**PK**

Comment: Nice link, thanks for that, but I couldn't see the Contacts app icon anywhere... did I miss it ?

Comment: Thanks for the info, the app icons were only an example. The first link is more of what I'm looking for, although I would prefer to see Apple's versions rather than a recreation of them.

Comment: add another link in the post. Here it is anyway http://www.iphonestudio.co.uk/page/iphone_icon_gallery